# Why is my label nil after starting my app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've created a simple app just for training purposes. The "Tap me" button causes a segue to the `ChildViewController` and set the `testLabel` value to `"Checking label..."`.

My code of "Tap me" button looks like this

```
@IBAction func tapMeButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    animateButton()
    daysLabel.text = array[counter]
    counter += 1
    if counter == array.count {
        counter = 0
    }
    
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueTest", sender: self)
      
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "segueTest" {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ChildViewController
    if let label = destinationVC.testLabel {
        label.text = "Checking label..."
    }
```

My ChildViewController is just an Outlet of my label:

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

I am aware that I have to check if my `testlabel` is/isn't `nil`, but why is that? Why can't I assign a value to my `testLabel`?

Comment: Because the controller's view (and any subview, such as your label) has not been loaded yet. Once that happens, the system calls `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Alladinian do you mean `viewDidLoad` in my `ChildViewController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is totally wrong:

```
let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ChildViewController
if let label = destinationVC.testLabel {
    label.text = "Checking label..."
}
```

You must never change another view controller's interface. (And anyway you can't, because the label has not been loaded at the time your are preparing for the segue.) Properly speaking, `testLabel` should have been declared `private` to prevent exactly this sort of thing.

You must set a string property of the ChildViewController itself. It is then up to the ChildViewController, in its `viewDidLoad`, to discover this and populate its own interface.

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var testLabel: UILabel!
    var testString: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let s = self.testString {
            self.testLabel.text = s
        }
    }

}
```

And now you are free to set `testString` in the new view controller.

Comment: I often think about how much better it would be if the default code generation for IBOutlet was promoting `private` (btw it should also be `strong` - another one bad default). There are countless examples of code abusing loadView etc just as a "workaround".

Comment: Also (totally unnecessary - forgive me for polluting your comment section :P ) since the label's text is optional, one could do just: `testLabel?.text = testString` (or of course without the `?`).

Comment: Thank you very much @matt. Now I understand everything. I've edited my code and it's working now.

Comment: @Alladinian "btw it should also be strong" I don't see why.

Comment: One more question... Can I use `testLabel?.text` instead of `if let` method in my `viewDidLoad` func?

Comment: @matt It's because the label is owned by the controller. There is a nice (old) [thread here](https://twitter.com/layoutsubviews/status/1030983794063421440) including comments from some folks from Apple.

Comment: @Alladinian nonetheless, the label's superview is already retaining it, there is no need for a double retain unless you plan to remove it from the superview but keep it on hand: the chain of ownership already goes v.c, main view, label, why bypass that with a complication???

Comment: @leopoldubz sure, it's just a matter of aesthetics at that point

Comment: @matt I hear you. This is a good point, but IBOutlet is not only for views. Furthermore, what you said would also be true for a programmatically-created label as well. Would you mark that as weak too? (I know, I’m probably knitpicking... just enjoying discussing this stuff )